# stack overflow while calculing permutations or a string in Scala

Tags: string, scala, permutation

All is in the title, and the code is here:

```
implicit class utils(val chaîne: String) {

    def permutations1(): List[String] = {
        if (chaîne.length() == 0) List()
        else
        if (chaîne.length() == 1) List(chaîne)
        else  {
            val retour1=for {i:Int <- 0 to chaîne.length() - 2
                 chaîne_réduite = chaîne.drop(i)
                 liste_avec_chaîne_réduite = chaîne_réduite.permutations1()
                 une_chaîne_réduite_et_permutée <- liste_avec_chaîne_réduite
                 j <- 0 to une_chaîne_réduite_et_permutée.length()
            }
            yield new StringBuilder(une_chaîne_réduite_et_permutée).insert(j, chaîne(j)).toString

            retour1.toList
        }
    }
}
```

Can you explain me why it does not work and eventually correct my code to make it avoid the stack overflow?

Comment: Can you please explain the code, how it should work? Btw.: French identifiers make it hard to take the code and test/modify it because of the fancy characters.

Comment: ok : the method permutations1 is added to the string class; after trivial cases (0 and 1), the general case treatment consists in extracting each character; and to replace it in all possible positions in all the permutations of the remaining characters. I suggest you to consider instead the other answer I gave, because it seems to be more simpler and shorter

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)? Thus you may only run any code with very limited length of strings.

To make it work on a reasonable string lengths careful optimization is required. For instance, to improve the performance you may try `@tailrec` optimization.

Representation in the form of `String` and `StringBuilder` is very inefficient for the task. Try `List` of `Char` for instance.

Comment: but the problem is not the time but the memory space too huge

Comment: and I can prove it can be done : in scala.collections there is a permutations method which can create an iterator over all the permutations of a string(but I want to do it myself!)

Comment: Definitely not NP-complete, much worse than that, as the output size is not polynomial in the size of the input. Yet, can be done for reasonably small inputs.

Comment: The problem is the endless loop for even short Strings, not NP-completeness and the like. "xy".permutations1 already raises the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself:

```
implicit class utils (val chaîne: String) {
  def permutations1 : Seq [String] = {
    if (chaîne.size == 1) Seq (chaîne)
    else chaîne.flatMap (x => chaîne.filterNot (_ == x).permutations1.map (x + _))
  }
}
```

Comment: ZipWithIndex returns an indexedSeq of a tuple, so to flatMap it you need a function which takes a tuple of char and int, best what you can do is `chaîne.zipWithIndex flatMap { case (x: Char, i: Int) => chaîne.drop(i).permutations2.map(x + _) }`, but i guess that would just confuse you

Comment: @gourlaysama:yes, I also think but, new to stackoverflow, I don't know how to highlight code in comments having line headers respected;

Comment: @alexlv:I tried, but I have a stack overflow error, and this code works: `    def permutations3 : Seq[String] =
        {
            if(chaîne.size == 1)
                Seq(chaîne);
            else
                chaîne.flatMap(x => chaîne.filterNot(_ == x).permutations3.map(x +));
        }` gosh! is it possible to have comments code formatted like answers's code?

Comment: @alexlv: I gave you a working code, but it has a default : it only handles strings having no repeated chars, and I wanted by changing the working example to have a code working with all strings (even if I should remove duplicates at the end of the permutations search, but it's another story)

Comment: @alex : do you know how to avoid the stack overflow error?or why does it occur?

Comment: @lolveley: No, code in comments is only very limited possible with backticks, but no newlines. If you have an answer (`(x +)`?) edit your own answer and don't post answers which don't work. You might post intermediate steps with related questions in your question.